constexpr if generates both controlflow paths?
I made an if-constexpr statement and it seems to generate both workflow paths...?
running this code :
#include <iostream>

class Chaste {
    template<typename T>
    friend struct TheChosenOne;
private:
    int x = 0;
    Chaste() = default;
    Chaste(int x): x(x) {}
};



int main() {
    std::allocator<Chaste> alloc{};
    Chaste* new_node = std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Chaste>>::allocate(alloc, 1);
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<Chaste, int>){
        new(new_node) Chaste(5);
    }else{
        static_assert(false);
    }
    return 0;
}


somehow I get both the static_assert and private constructor call CE`s:

/home/bibaboba/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/bibaboba/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp:18:31: error: ‘Chaste::Chaste(int)’ is private within this context
   18 |         new(new_node) Chaste(5);
      |                               ^
/home/bibaboba/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp:9:5: note: declared private here
    9 |     Chaste(int x): x(x) {}
      |     ^~~~~~
/home/bibaboba/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp:20:23: error: static assertion failed
   20 |         static_assert(false);
      |                       ^~~~~

According to cppreference, only one flow should be compiled (the one with static_assert) since the is_constructible expression is false, so why is a private constructor call CE generated?

I know both flows may be generated if the condition in an if-statement isn't constexpr, but isn't is_constructible constexpr?

tl;dr - if constexpr can discard branches only in a template, and only when the condition is dependent on template parameters. Furthermore, static_assert(false) in that situation is only well-formed since C++23

You should not even have to use that constexpr if in main, make your Chaste class itself only compilable it it is constructible from int and make your Chaste class itself specialize on allocator type... so all in all the design looks a bit weird (maybe it is the result of you trying to make an MRE)
